# How to convert polyline with weight to polygon in Leaflet?

Tags: routes, geometry, leaflet, polyline

I need to allow user to draw a route (using polyline) with specified road radius (visually it was done with "weight" parameter).

Visually it looks like that:

[image]

So I'm wondering how can build a polygon around this polyline with some offset? Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I made it with JSTS library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsts).

It's easy:

```
//pathCoords should be an array of jsts.geom.Coordinate
var pathCoords = [];
var geometryFactory = new jsts.geom.GeometryFactory();

// on what distance new polygon should be built
var distance = (meters * 0.0001) / 111.12;
var shell = geometryFactory.createLineString(pathCoords);

// building a new polygon
var polygon = shell.buffer(distance);

// finally get your new polygon coordinates
var polygonCoords = polygon.getCoordinates();
```

Comment: I tried JSTS library on my web application and it's working perfectly, I need to do the same on Android but I couldn't find a similar library for Android or Java

Answer (score 2):

Like you said, you can use the `getLatLngs` method of `L.Polyline` to access the coordinates and use them to initialize a `L.Polygon`. If you need to access the weight that's been set on the polyline you can do so by using it's options object:

```
var polyline = new L.Polyline([[25, -25], [25, 25], [-25, 25], [-25, -25]], {
    weight: 10,
}).addTo(map);

var polygon = new L.Polygon(polyline.getLatLngs(), {
    weight: polyline.options.weight
}).addTo(map);
```

You could even use the entire options object if you've got more things you'll need to duplicate:

```
var polygon = new L.Polygon(polyline.getLatLngs(), polyline.options).addTo(map);
```

Since `L.Polygon` is extended from `L.Polyline` that won't be a problem since it has the same options.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear about question, I don't need to apply a polyline's style to polygon, I need to build one around polyline. I attached a new picture for better understanding.